# Why isn't the background color of the top navigation bar showing?

Tags: html, css

Okay so I am making a website and I wanted to put a top navigation bar. However for some reason the background-color doesn't show, it's just transparent.
CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 700; line-height: 26.4px; } h3 { font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 700; line-height: 15.4px; } p { font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; line-height: 20px; } blockquote { font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif; font-size: 21px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; line-height: 30px; } pre { font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; line-height: 18.5714px; }
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="./projects.html">Projects</a>
  <a href="./bots.html">Bots</a>
  <a href="./socials.html">Socials</a>
  <a href="./inquiries.html">Inquiries</a>
  <a href="./other.html">Other</a>
</div>
```

Comment: typo, you have an extra `}`

Answer (score 2):

Just fix your css syntax
https://jsfiddle.net/ckn0xqhL/

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 26.4px;
}

h3 {
    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 15.4px;
}

p {
    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
}

blockquote {
    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 30px;
}

pre {
    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 18.5714px;
}
```